# Escaping quotes in PHP with variable

Tags: php, escaping, quotes

There are numerous question on Stackoverflow concerning this but I have not been able to solve this still.

I'm trying to put multiple variables inside global attribute data-*. The output should be:

```
data-info="23;thisWeek"
```

The 23 comes from a database: $row["id"], and thisWeek from a variable: $categori1.

I've tried:

```
echo "<tr data-info=" .fixSlashes($row["id"], $categori1); " class=\"tableclass\"><td>"
```

Then

```
<?php
function fixSlashes($idP, $categoriP){
$str = addslashes($idP . ";" .$categoriP);
return $str;
}
?>
```

But something goes wrong. No error message, but the behaviour is wrong. It works if I just write:

```
echo "<tr data-info="data-info="23;thisWeek" class=\"tableclass\"><td>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not outputting the html correctly. Note the escaped quotes around the fix Slashes function. Also note the "." instead of the semicolon.

```
"<tr data-info=\"" .fixSlashes($row["id"], $categori1) . "\" class=\"tableclass\"><td>"
```

If you want to see all errors include the following code. This would have caught the semicolon error.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<tr data-info=" .fixSlashes($row["id"], $categori1); " class=\"tableclass\"><td>"
```

You have a semicolon (;) where the concat operator (.) should be.  Umm, after the fixSlashes function.  Before the class suffix string.

You're ending the echo statement prematurely, before the "class=\"tableclass\">" can be appended.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to piggy-back, but half the answers are getting the one problem and half the answers are getting the other problem.

You need to fix your semi-colon to a period (concat) as @MingShun said.
You need to get quotes (escaped) around your data as @JimmyScray said.

```
echo "<tr data-info=\"" .fixSlashes($row["id"]. $categori1). "\" class=\"tableclass\"><td>";
```

Comment: It worked just changing the semicolon to "." and no need to add the extra escape for quotes.

Comment: If you don't fix your quotes then you have malformed HTML. Yes, it may work now and in the browser you are testing it on, but you should always aim for well-formed HTML which means getting the quotes right...

Comment: Thank you, Peter. I will add this!

Answer (score 0):

Use escape sequence for displaying double quotations and use single quotations for id (i.e $row['id'])

```
 echo "<tr data-info=\" $row['id'];$categori1\" class=\"tableclass\"><td>";
```

Comment: You have escaped quotes that were being used to delineate OP's string. Note the use of the `.` as a concatenation operator - that's OUTSIDE a string. Your line doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah! I copied the code above and edited it. Forgot to remove the dot operator. thnx anyways:)
I have made the correction.